# replacing all decimal points in a string with ' point ' and maintaining same number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string where I want to replace all decimal points with 'number point number'
e.g.

input:

> from 27.14% to 13.2% for stable and moderately stable variants,
>   respectively (P = 0.018 by one-tailed U-test; Fig. 3c).
>   Protein-destabilizing3 variants also tend to be rare5; we observed2
>   that median allele frequency decreased from 0.064% for

desired output:

> from 27 point 14% to 13 point 2% for stable and moderately stable
>   variants, respectively (P = 0 point 018 by one-tailed U-test; Fig.
>   3c). Protein-destabilizing3 variants also tend to be rare5; we
>   observed2 that median allele frequency decreased from 0 point 064% for

I have tried:

```
s = s.replace(/(\d(\d)?)\.(\d+)/g, "$1 point $3");
```

but the output is:

> from 27 point 4% to 13 point 2% for stable and moderately stable
>   variants, respectively (P = 0 point 8 by one-tailed U-test; Fig. 3c).
>   Protein-destabilizing3 variants also tend to be rare5; we observed2
>   that median allele frequency decreased from 0 point 4% for

Hence when there are more than one digit after the decimal space it only replaces these digits with the last one e.g.

> 27.14% --> 27 point 4%

Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/huyijediyu/edit?js,console)

Comment: You can literally copy the code from the [code generator at rege101](https://regex101.com/r/Zy0xMx/1/codegen?language=javascript) if you're unfamiliar with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra capturing group. You could just use 2 groups instead

```
(\d\d?)\.(\d+)
```

In the replacement use

```
$1 point $2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O8PZAS/1)

Comment: While this is a good practice, the number of the capturing groups doesn't affect the correctness of the output.

Comment: I see, you are right, the OP's regex matches as well. @which_command Can you add the codesnippet to your question that fails the expected outcome?